# SendGrid Cc and Bcc not working on PHP

Tags: php, sendgrid, bcc, carbon-copy

I'm using sendgrid with php, I've used both options the client library and the curl option. So far, I've been able to send emails directly with the addTo option with no problem. But when I try to add Cc or Bcc options, the email still gets sent but the copies are never delivered. Are there any known issues with the php version? In other project the java library works just fine.

Here is a simple piece of code I'm trying to make it work

```
<?php
require ('sendgrid/sendgrid-php.php');

$sendgrid = new SendGrid('user', 'pwd');

$mail = new SendGrid\Email();
$mail ->addTo("mymail@gmail.com");
$mail ->addCc("other@otherserver.com");
$mail ->setFrom("sender@server.com");
$mail ->setSubject("TEST");
$mail->setHtml("<h1>Example</h1>");
$sendgrid->send($mail);

?>
```

Comment: var_dump($mail) and post the output

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The documentation does not seem to have addCc method. 
You can try these alternatives.

```
$mail = new SendGrid\Email();
$mail->addTo('foo@bar.com')->
       addTo('someotheraddress@bar.com')->
       addTo('another@another.com');
```

or

```
$mail   = new SendGrid\Email();
$mail->addBcc('foo@bar.com');
$sendgrid->send($mail);
```

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php#bcc

Comment: Multiple addTo does the trick to mimic the Bcc, however I need the emails to be sent with their respective Cc and Bcc. The method addCc does not appear on the documentation but it does on the library.

Comment: They have removed addCc from the documentation. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/commit/7d5e428321db6419829eb52a206364b072182d81

Comment: You can also chk this issue here. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/83

Comment: That is definitely good to know. Thanks, I guess I'll take the phpMailer approach for this

Answer (score 0):

```
Find script with CC and BCC 
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("test@example.com", "Example User");
$email->addCc("test@example.com", "Example User");
$email->addBcc("test@example.com", "Example User");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```